# Native script list template binding not working

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I cannot make working binding with ListView and template.

```
<ListView #userListView [items]="usersViewList" (itemTap)="onItemTap($event)">
    <template let-user="item" let-i="index">
        <GridLayout columns="auto">
            <Label [text]="user.name" col="0"></Label>  
        </GridLayout>
    </template>
</ListView>
```

at cration time user.name is assigned properly, but later if I call.

```
user.name = "other name";
```

Nothing happens.

Binding context is set to item in usersViewList correctly. But no changes are propagated to individual list item ever.

Thank for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call ***user.name*** "later" (guessing in your code behind component file?).
If you need to access the tapped item you can use the index of the tapped item and then you can grab it from your items array like

```
usersViewList[index].name
```

You have also **itemTap** which provides you with arguments where you8 can directly access the tapped index like show [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/release/app/ui-category/listview/creating-listview/creating-listview.component.ts#L30)

The best practice, in this case, is to compare your code with a sample that demonstrates the exact same case. [Here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/release/app/ui-category/listview/creating-listview/creating-listview.component.html) you can find one. And many other examples are posted [in this section](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/tree/release/app/common-screens-category/lists-category) of the same application.

Comment: So in other words: Binding to binding context is not working for listview items.